# How to get documents where KEY is greater than X

Tags: python, mongodb

i am recording user's daily usage of my platform.

structures of documents in mongodb are like that:

```
_id: X
day1:{
    loginCount = 4
    someDict { x:y, z:m }
    }
day2:{
    loginCount = 5
    someDict { a:b, c:d }
    }
```

then, i need to get last 2 day's user stats which belongs to user X.

how can i get values whose days are greater than two days ago? (like using '$gte' command?)

Comment: Why dont you use dates for your days?

Comment: Also if you keep updating your document like this you will run into the document max limit eventually. I think your datastructure is "mmm" suboptimal.

Comment: +1 for @RickyA : just use datetime objects to make life even simpler!

Comment: RickyA s second comment is absolutely correct, since document size limit is 16 MB. Since what you are doing is kinda of a logging to me, you can make a document per login with datetime and user id fields. Then you can make records with simple queries or aggregation framework or mapreduce

Comment: @RickyA what will happen when i hold date objects as a day?

Comment: @fga 16 mb is far enough.

Comment: @fga if i do it like you said, per datetie and userID field, collection will grow too much, after a while update and insert operations will be costful. tried it, this nested structure is far better on inserting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, if you insist on this scheme try this:

```
{
_id: Usemongokeyhere
userid: X
days: [
         {day:IsoDate(2013-08-12 00:00), 
          loginCount: 10,
          #morestuff
         },
         {day:IsoDate(2013-08-13 00:00), 
          loginCount: 11,
          #morestuff
         },
      ]
},
#more users
```

Then you can query like:

```
db.items.find(
    {"days.day":{$gte:ISODate("2013-08-30T00:00:00.000Z"),
                $lt: ISODate("2013-08-31T00:00:00.000Z")
                }
    }
)
```

Comment: +1 Schema is better than the existing one.I would accept this answer

Answer (score 2):

Unless there is any change in the question, i am answering based on this schema.

```
_id: X
day1:{
   loginCount:4
   someDict:{ x:y, z:m }
}
day2:{
  loginCount:5
  someDict:{ a:b, c:d }
}
```

**Answer**:

last 2 day's user stats which belongs to user X.

You cannot get it from mongo side with operators like $gte, with this structure, because you get the whole days when do query for user X. The document contains information about all days and keeping dynamic values as keys is in my opinion a bad practice. You can retrieve a documents by defining fields like db.collection.find({_id:X},{day1:1,day2:1})

However you have to know what the keys are and i am not sure how you keep day1 and day2 as key iso date, timestamp? Depending on how you hold it, you can write fields on the query by writing yesterday and before yesterday as date string or timestamp and get your required information.

Comment: unfortunately, i cannot tell day1:1, since day1: { loginCount=4; someDict={};}

Comment: @AlperTokgöz Why? As i run the query on my test collection i get { "_id" : "X", "day1" : { "loginCount" : 4, "someDict" : { "x" : "y", "z" : "m" } }, "day2" : { "loginCount" : 5, "someDict" : { "a" : "b", "c" : "d" } } } meaning information about two days for user X. Is this behaviour not desired or did i misunderstand your problem?